# SAP B1 Query for total AR Invoice per Warehouse Code

Tags: sapb1

can anyone help with my query for getting the total AR INVOICE per Warehouse code? Tried some queries but none of it work. Thanks

| Total AR Invoice | Warehouse Code |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

I want it display only two columns "Total AR Invoice" and "Warehouse Code"

Answer (score 0):

this should get it

```
 Select 
 SUM(LineTotal) [AR Invoice Total] 
,WhsCode from inv1 
 group by
 WhsCode
```

the group by is the key part here.